# Uploading node.js app in bluemix

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud

I created a Node.js app that works locally. It contains various routes as well as a login/registration system. Everything is fine. I can login,register,and apply all requests(GET,POST,PUT,DEL) through postman!

Now I want to post that app in bluemix. I created a **manifest.yml** file as shown.

```
applications:
name: larissa-capstone
memory: 256M
disk_quota: 512M 
buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
domain: mybluemix.net
command: node server/web-server.js
```

However after running the push command **cf push**,I get the following error.

```
Incorrect Usage. The push command requires an app name. The app name can be 
supplied as an argument or with a manifest.yml file.
```

But I have the app's name in the manifest file. Why is this happening?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `manifest.yml` does not have the [required format](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html). The `name` needs to be preceded with a dash and the other lines need to be indented. Try something like this:

```
applications:
- name: larissa-capstone
  memory: 256M
  disk_quota: 512M 
  buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
  domain: mybluemix.net
  command: node server/web-server.js
```